# A simple norm estimation: $|a\Psi-b\Phi|\leq c|\Psi-\Phi|$?

Tags: calculus

Assume that $\Phi,\Psi\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $a,b\in[0,1]$ and denote by $|\cdot|$ the euclidean norm. Is there a way to find a constant $c>0$ such that
$$|a\Psi-b\Phi|\leq c|\Psi-\Phi|?$$

Maybe via some Lipschitz continuity of some linear or affine function?

Comment: What are $\Phi, \Psi$?

Comment: I changed notation, $\Psi,\Phi$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Point of clarification: does the same $c>0$ need to work for all vectors $\Phi, \Psi \in \mathbb R^d$? Or given $\Phi,\Psi$, do we need to find a $c>0$ that works only for those two particular vectors?

Comment: I am grateful for ideas for both cases. Ideally, $c$ depends only on fixed $a,b\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because if $\Psi = \Phi$ the right side is $0$ but the left in general is not.

Comment: Thank you. This was a serious blindspot!